# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in vb.NET

Tags: vb.net

I've got this error that said String was not recognized as a valid DateTime, can anyone help me what's wrong here?

```
Dim Br As New BL.Bridge
    Me.DataSource = Br.List(DateTime.ParseExact(Me.txtTempo.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) 'error  is right here
    Me.ReportPath = "~/report/JaTem.rpt"
    Me.HasPrintButton = True
    Me.ShowGroupTree = False
    If DataSource.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Me.HasPrintButton = True
        Server.Transfer("~/report/rpt.aspx")
    Else
        lblMessage.Text = "No Data!"
    End If
```

if `txtTempo` is filled with date it's work, but when `txtTempo` is empty, it's getting error

Comment: So what's in `Me.txtJatem.Text` at the time?  Presumably it's not recognised as a valid `DateTime` in that format.

Comment: for example, when i'm add "01-12-2004" it's work, but when it's empty it's getting error

Comment: Obviously there should be some value so that it can convert,else it will show error as no value is available to parse or convert.Null cannot be converted know

Comment: you could try adding a condition check then parse the value if its not empty..right ?

Comment: @utility but, why it's showing an error rather than notification message?

Comment: @JTR you should make them to check the empty values then pop a message a message or notification as you like 
for eg: if txtJatem.Text is not empty you could proceed with convertion

Comment: Use TryParse first, or test the content before using ParseExact.

Comment: There is a `TryParseExact` method.

Comment: how to use TryParseExact? I'mnew in vb.net, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) method that you are using will give an error when it runs into data that it can't handle. You need to do one of 3 things,

> - validate the data before using the ParseExact method
> - use [exception handling](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/315965) to catch the error and notify your user
> - or you can use the [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) which will give you a Boolean result to indicate if the method succeeded. You would use it something like this.:

```
Imports System.Globalization

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim Date1Data As String = ""
        Dim Date2Data As String = "25-09-2015"
        Dim result As DateTime
        If DateTime.TryParseExact(Date1Data, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, result) Then
            'handle it here
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Format Error")
        End If

        If DateTime.TryParseExact(Date2Data, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, result) Then
            Console.WriteLine(result) 'handle it here
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Format Error")
        End If
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

or modifying your code something like this should work.

```
Dim Br As New BL.Bridge
Dim result as Date

If DateTime.TryParseExact(Me.txtJatem.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, result) Then
    Me.DataSource = Br.List(result) 'error  is right here
    Me.ReportPath = "~/report/JaTem.rpt"
    Me.HasPrintButton = True
    Me.ShowGroupTree = False
    If DataSource.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Me.HasPrintButton = True
        Server.Transfer("~/report/rpt.aspx")
    Else
        lblMessage.Text = "No Data!"
    End If
Else
    lblMessage.Text = "Format Error, please check input and try again"
End If
```

Comment: can you check my updated question? how to write code like you make if i'm only used one textfield?? i'm really sorry, because i'm beginner in vb.net

Comment: Ok, I used a console application so you could easily test, will modify to use your field names

Comment: oh my, thank you so much sir, it's really work perfectly! :D